# Union of two pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

Say I have two data frames:

df1:

```
  A
0 a
1 b
```

df2:

```
  A
0 a
1 c
```

I want the result to be the **union** of the two frames with an **extra column** showing the source data frame that the row belongs to. In case of duplicates, duplicates should be removed and the respective extra column should show both sources:

```
  A  B
0 a  df1, df2
1 b  df1
2 c  df2
```

I can get the concatenated data frame (df3) without duplicates as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

I can't think of/find a method to have control over what element goes where. How can I add the extra column?

Thank you very much for any tips.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Merge with an `indicator` argument, and remap the result:

```
m = {'left_only': 'df1', 'right_only': 'df2', 'both': 'df1, df2'}

result = df1.merge(df2, on=['A'], how='outer', indicator='B')
result['B'] = result['B'].map(m)

result
   A         B
0  a  df1, df2
1  b       df1
2  c       df2
```

Comment: Excellent! Could you add how to do the same for intersection? outer->inner?

Comment: @LeonRai `df1.merge(df2, on=['A'], how='inner').assign(B='df1, df2')` (since intersection implies membership in both)

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Use the command below:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.assign(source='df1'), df2.assign(source='df2')]) \
    .groupby('A') \
    .aggregate(list) \
    .reset_index()
```

The result will be:

```
   A      source
0  a  [df1, df2]
1  b       [df1]
2  c       [df2]
```

The `assign` will add a column named `source` with value `df1` and `df2` to your dataframes. `groupby` command groups rows with same `A` value to single row. `aggregate` command describes how to aggregate other columns (`source`) for each group of rows with same `A`. I have used `list` aggregate function so that the `source` column be the list of values with same `A`.

Answer (score 2):

We use outer join to solve this -

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','c']})
df1['col1']='df1'
df2['col2']='df2'
df=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A'], how="outer").fillna('')
df['B']=df['col1']+','+df['col2']
df['B'] = df['B'].str.strip(',')
df=df[['A','B']]
df

   A        B
0  a  df1,df2
1  b      df1
2  c      df2
```

Comment: pleasure Leon :)